# Does making a struct volatile make all its members volatile?

Tags: c++

If I have:

```
struct whatever {
int data;
};

volatile whatever test;
```

will `test.data` be volatile too?

Comment: Excellent question. I read that having a `volatile` member function only makes the `this` pointer volatile, so members will be read from memory each time they are accessed but are not "officially" volatile.

Comment: Possibly [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044565/volatile-struct-semantics), but still a good question.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Another question can be asked (or simply another way to look at the original question):

### Does making a struct `const` make all its members `const`?

If I have:

```
struct whatever { int data; };

const whatever test;
```

Will test.data be `const` too?

My answer is : Yes. If you declare an object of type `whatever` with `const` then all its members will be `const` too

Similarly, if you declare an object of type `whatever` with `volatile` then all its members will be `volatile` too, just like if you declare the object with `const`, all it's member will be `const` too.

`const` and `volatile` are two faces of the same coin; they're so that the Standard often refers to them as `cv-qualifiers`.

---

Quoting from the Standard ($7.1.5.1/8)

> [Note: volatile is *a hint to the
>   implementation* to avoid aggressive
>   optimization **involving the object**
>   because **the value of the object** might
>   be changed by means undetectable by an
>   implementation. See 1.9 for detailed
>   semantics. In general, the semantics
>   of volatile are intended to be the
>   same in C + + as they are in C. ]

That means, if your object is an instance of a struct, then the compiler cannot *avoid aggressive optimization involving the object*, **unless** it avoids aggressive optimization of each of it's members. (Otherwise, how else it can avoid optimization involving the object?)

---

Related topic:

[Why do we use volatile keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437527/why-do-we-use-volatile-keyword-in-c/4437555#4437555)

Comment: It is important to note that the constness is propagated to immediate memembers only. If your struct holds a pointer to some object, the pointer itself will be const (e.g.. you won't be able to reassign it), but you will be able to change the object being pointed at. (assuming your struct isn't hoding a pointer to const)

Comment: If you have a `const` object, all its members aren't `const`. For example, you can have `mutable` members.

Comment: @PabloArias The `const` propagates because if class A has a member b of class B, this member will be const, so b's member's will be const as well. With a pointer, only the address pointed to is constant. By dereferencing it, you are not modifying the pointer itself (which is constant), but the object it points to.

Answer (score -3):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/145yc477%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

To declare the object pointed to by the pointer as const or volatile, use a declaration of the form:

```
const char *cpch;
volatile char *vpch;
```

To declare the value of the pointer — that is, the actual address stored in the pointer — as const or volatile, use a declaration of the form:

```
char * const pchc;
char * volatile pchv;
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question