# Volatile related error in C++ code

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, gcc, volatile

Can you help me to understand why the compiler is giving me those error messages? I believe members of volatile objects are volatile too. I'm referring from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479597/does-making-a-struct-volatile-make-all-its-members-volatile). But it shows up that if we have a structure:

```
struct someStruct
{
    int d;
};
```

And 'p' is a defined like:

```
volatile someStruct* volatile* p;
```

`&(*p)->d` have the following type 'int* volatile*' instead of 'volatile int* volatile*'. Below is the actual code on which I'm working on.

---

The lines (marked with error 1 & 2) is where the compiler throws an error messages:

```
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct ThreadInfo
{
    bool bWaiting = false;

    bool bWorking = false;
};

struct lThreadInfo
{
    ThreadInfo d;
    lThreadInfo *pNextList = nullptr;
} volatile *volatile lThreads(nullptr);

thread_local ThreadInfo* currentThr(nullptr);

void CreateThread_(void (*pFunc)(ThreadInfo*))
{
    volatile lThreadInfo* volatile* p = &lThreads;

    for(; *p; p = &(*p)->pNextList); //**//error 1!**

    *p = new lThreadInfo;

    CreateThread(
            nullptr,                   // default security attributes
            0,                      // use default stack size
            (long unsigned int (*)(void*))pFunc,       // thread function name
            &(*p)->d,          // argument to thread function     **//error 2!**
            0,                      // use default creation flags
            nullptr);
}
```

The errors messages are the following:

```
error 1: invalid conversion from 'lThreadInfo* volatile*' to 'volatile lThreadInfo* volatile*' [-fpermissive]
error 2: invalid conversion from 'volatile void*' to 'LPVOID {aka void*}' [-fpermissive]
```

<sup>**Note**: I know that volatile have nothing to do with thread-safety, so don't bother telling me so.</sup>
<sup>**Note1**: I'm using mingw64 compiler on windows.</sup>

Comment: For the second error, you will need a `const_cast` to cast off the `volatile` for the Windows API function call. For the first error, the member `pNextList` will need to be `volatile` as well (or remove the `volatile` from `p`).

Comment: But shouldn't creating an object with volatile specifier automatically makes all it's sub-objects volatile also?

Comment: `lThreadInfo::pNextList` has the type `lThreadInfo*`. If you have a `lThreadInfo` object that's `volatile`, e.g. `lThreadInfo volatile o;`, then `o.pNextList` is `lThreadInfo* volatile`. The cv-qualifiers are always applied to the "outmost" type, not the type pointed to.

Comment: So then how can I store a pointer to this sub-object with which I can modify it like it's from volatile type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pNextList`, through a `volatile` access-path, is `volatile` too. But `pNextList` is the **pointer**. The **pointee** type has the same cv-qualification as before.

That is, for

```
struct A
{
    lThreadInfo* p;
};

someStruct volatile* volatile* p;
```

- `*p` is an lvalue of type `someStruct volatile* volatile`
- `(*p)->d` is an lvalue of type `lThreadInfo* volatile`.

So in the type of `(*p)->d` you're missing the volatile between `lThreadInfo` and `*`. [expr.ref]/4:

> If `E2` is a non-static data member and the type of `E1` is “*cq1 vq1*
>   `X`”, and the type of `E2` is “*cq2 vq2* `T`”, the expression
>   designates the named member of the object designated by the first
>   expression. If `E1` is an lvalue, then `E1.E2` is an lvalue; if `E1`
>   is an xvalue, then `E1.E2` is an xvalue; otherwise, it is a prvalue.
>   **Let the notation *vq12* stand for the “union” of *vq1* and *vq2*; that is, if *vq1* or *vq2* is `volatile`, then
>   *vq12* is `volatile`.** Similarly, let the notation *cq12* stand for the “union” of *cq1* and *cq2* ; that is, if *cq1* or *cq2* is
>   `const`, then *cq12* is `const`. If `E2` is declared to be a mutable
>   member, then the type of `E1.E2` is “*vq12* `T`”. If `E2` is not
>   declared to be a mutable member, then **the type of `E1.E2` is “*cq12*
>   *vq12* `T`”**.

*vq1* is `volatile` and *vq2* is empty. Thus *vq12* is `volatile`. Thus the type of the expression is `volatile T`, which is `lThreadInfo* volatile`.