# cv-qualified struct's member is not similarly cv-qualified

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++14, type-traits

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4479652/1430927), the following code should be compiled without error:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace
{

struct A { int i; };

volatile A a{};
static_assert(std::is_volatile< decltype(a) >{});
static_assert(std::is_volatile< decltype(a.i) >{});

}
```

but there is a hard error:

```
main.cpp:10:1: error: static_assert failed
static_assert(std::is_volatile< decltype(a.i) >{});
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

[Live example with *clang 3.6.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bb6be081c916960).

Is it a clang bug or am I missing something substantial?

**ADDITIONAL:**

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace
{

struct A { int i; };

const A a{};
static_assert(std::is_const< decltype(a) >{});
static_assert(std::is_const< decltype(a.i) >{});

}
```

Exactly the same behaviour for the latter code snippet.

**ADDITIONAL:**

```
static_assert(std::is_volatile< std::remove_pointer_t< decltype(&a.i) > >{});
```

not cause an error.

Comment: Besides,`static_assert` with no message is a C++1z extension

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname The same error for C++11 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f2c7e25c543fb28

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour; the current `decltype` isn't testing what you think it tests. You have to change your `decltype` if you want to test for `volatile`-ness.

It is possible to copy a value out and drop `volatile`-ness. But a reference must be <strike>volatile</strike> reference-to-volatile.

```
int foo() {
    int i = a.i;            // volatile not needed
    volatile int &i = a.i;  // volatile needed
}
```

The `decltype` is <strike>treating `a.i` as an rvalue, not an lvalue,</strike> doing what `decltype` does by default and is doing a "naive" text analysis and reporting the type of `A::i` as written in the source code; therefore, `decltype(a.i)` is `int`.

Putting `()` around an expression in `decltype` changes its behaviour (in good ways usually, for this kind of question), giving us an lvalue when appropriate. Therefore, `decltype(( a.i ))` is `volatile int &`.

Now, you might expect that `is_volatile< volatile int & >::value` would be true. But it's not. We need to remove the reference before we can test for the `volatile`-ness.

```
static_assert(std::is_volatile< std::remove_reference_t<decltype((a.i))> >{});
```

Finally, you might be surprised that `volatile int &` isn't volatile according to `is_volatile`. But I guess it's because references are really very like pointers - and the 'pointer' inside a reference isn't volatile, even if the object pointed to is volatile. That's my theory anyway. `const int&` also does not satisfy `is_const`.

Comment: The semantic of reference is almost like *dereferenced pointer*.

Comment: @T.C., my fault. I didn't read my test results correctly. I think I just assumed it would be `is_const` and wasn't expecting the evidence to contradict me. I think it's really weird though!

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback! This answer has changed a lot. It was incorrect at many times, should be reasonably good now. (I'm still not entirely satisfied with it :-) )

Comment: "[...] and is doing a "naive" text analysis and reporting the type of A::i as written in the source code; therefore, decltype(a.i) is int." Why is it (formally)?

Comment: @black, most of what I know about `decltype` comes from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype#Semantics). I'm happy to change it, or for others to change it, if it can be improved; but I'm not a language lawyer. Also, perhaps it's not necessary to fully explain `decltype` here. It should suffice, I think, to tell the OP that unparenthesized doesn't do what the OP expected.

Comment: What about `decltype((a).i)`?