# How to use volatile on a struct in C++?

Tags: c++

This is how I can make a `volatile` variable:

```
volatile int i;
```

But how can I make a `struct` instance `volatile`, is this correct?

```
volatile MyStruct s1;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044565

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479597

Comment: This looks correct, basically you do the same as you would for `const`.